# StandardScaler returns all zeros

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to transform my dictionary with `StandardScaler()`, but it gives me only zeros.
How to fix it?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
import pandas as pd

param ={
  "user_id": 22058,
  "signup_day": 24,
  "signup_month": 2,
  "signup_year": 2015,
  "purchase_day": 18,
  "purchase_month": 4,
  "purchase_year": 2015,
  "purchase_value": 34,
  "age": 39,
  "source_Ads": 0,
  "source_Direct": 0,
  "source_SEO": 1,
  "browser_Chrome": 1,
  "browser_FireFox": 0,
  "browser_IE": 0,
  "browser_Opera": 0,
  "browser_Safari": 0,
  "sex_F": 0,
  "sex_M": 1
}

new = (pd.Series(param, index=['user_id', 'signup_day', 'signup_month', 'signup_year', 'purchase_day', 'purchase_month', 'purchase_year', 'purchase_value', 'age', 'source_Ads', 'source_Direct', 'source_SEO', 'browser_Chrome', 'browser_FireFox','browser_IE', 'browser_Opera', 'browser_Safari', 'sex_F', 'sex_M'])).values.reshape(1,-1)
print(new)

scaler = StandardScaler()
X_new = scaler.fit_transform(new)
print(X_new)
```

Results:

```
new = [[22058 24 2 2015 18 4 2015 34 39 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1]]

X_new =[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

`StandardScaler` is meant to scale columns of your data, here you have only one value per column so each of them is set to 0. Use it with multiple values per column and you might get the expected result !